# The function $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_A : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (v,w) \mapsto \langle Av, w\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra

here I've got a linear algebra related question:

---

For which set of matrices contained in $\mathbb{M}^{n \times n} \ $is the function $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_A : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (v,w) \mapsto \langle Av, w\rangle$ an inner product?

---

**Research effort**

First of all define $$S = \{UDU^T: U \ \text{is orthogonal, and} \ D \ \text{is a positive diagonal matrix} \}$$ Then all matrices in $S$ satisfy, but is it also true that every satisfying matrix is an element of $S$? I know that every satisfying matrix must be invertible, otherwise there would be a non-trivial element $v$ such that $\langle v, v\rangle_A = 0$. Moreover, $A$ must be symmetric to establish symmetry of $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_A$. My last observation is that $A$ connot have any negative eigenvalues, otherwise there exists a non-trivial vector v such that
$$\langle v,v \rangle_A = \lambda \langle v,v\rangle < 0$$
Can you help me to finish this?

Comment: So, Symmetric Positive Definite. Seems to me as correct. What do you think is incomplete?

Comment: Do you mean $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>_A:\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have it. Just note that you say $A$ cannot have any negative eigenvalues but moreover it must be true that 0 also cannot be an eigenvalues (otherwise $\langle v, v\rangle_A=0$ for the corresponding eigenvector.) Since you already know it is symmetric this means it is diagonalizable and all the eigenvalues are positive. Thus it is in the set $S$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also explain me why $A$ is **unitary** diagonizable?

Comment: @Koen: This is part of the conclusion of the spectral theorem since $A$ is self-adjoint.